# Selenium webdriver repeated downloads freezes programs

Tags: python, selenium

When downloading 1000+ pages, the python program slows down to the point where it looks to be stopped (although it is still running). This happens at about 300 pages.

I think my config may be incorrect in my download method. Any suggestions about what I may be doing wrong?

The code below is from a method called in a for loop.

```
    vdisplay = None
    browser = None

    try:
        if onLinux:
            vdisplay = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
            vdisplay.start()

        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        browser.set_page_load_timeout(40)  # seconds
        browser.get(requestUrl)
        wait = ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 40) # timeout after 40 seconds

        #convert to string and then to a soup object
        page = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        sourceSoup = BeautifulSoup(page)

    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()

    finally:
        #stop headless browser if on Linux
        if onLinux:
            if browser is not None:
                browser.close()
                browser.quit()

            if vdisplay is not None:
                vdisplay.stop()

    return sourceSoup
```

Comment: Do you have some information about how many requests are completed and pending when the freezing happens? Are all requests to the same site, and perhaps it cannot handle all of the requests concurrently?

Comment: They are all to the same site (my site, hosted on the same machine). No stats on open requests, how could I get those? The requests should have completed on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize each iteration of the loop was occurring synchronously. Are you getting any `TimeoutExceptions` thrown? If not -- this is a wild guess stab, but perhaps changing to `except Exception as e: print e` might reveal any `TimeoutExceptions`.

Comment: this code returns a page to the caller - what the caller code is doing with these pages ? Does the caller code stores them in an array or so ?

Comment: why are you starting a new browser for each page? Also, I notice that when `onLinux` is false, `browser.quit()` won't be called.